# How to create irregular and rounded shapes in Photoshop and/or Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, shapes

I'd like to recreate and make different permutations of the image below. What's the best approach to do this?

I tried doing this in Photoshop, however it doesn't look how I want it to and the shapes are too irregular. Is it not as flexible as doing it in Illustrator? I have little knowledge of Illustrator, so I'm unsure how to exactly manipulate the shapes in an arrangement like this.

[image]

Comment: Hi AnotherHay, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Hi AndrewH, I tried doing this on Ps, however it doesn't look like I wanted it to be, and kinda too irregular. It's not as flexible as maybe doing it on Ai? I have little knowledge of Ai so I'm unsure how to exactly manipulate shapes like on this arrangement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend doing this in a vector program. For my demo I am doing this in Illustrator.

Draw the background square.

Draw some paths that will separate the square.

[image: paths over background shape]

I then gave the paths a stroke and stroke width of 4. Pick a number for how much space you want from each object. I then selected all of the strokes and went to Object -> Expand, and expanded the stroke.

[image: strokes over background]

Select both the strokes and background and open the pathfinder options, Window -> Pathfinder and select "Divide".

Select the black stroke with the direct select tool and go to Select -> Same -> Fill Color and delete all of the black fills.

**In Illustrator CC**, select all of the blue objects and use the live corners to make the corners round.

**In Illustrator CS6**, and below, select all of the blue objects and go to Effect -> Stylize -> Round Corners.

Result

[image: Final Result]